# Matching columns using if statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby

I am trying to clean up typos in this dataset.

Database of employee names

```
First    Last    Location   
John     Smith   Calgary    
John     Smith   Toronto 
Joh      Smith   Toronto    
Steph    Sax     Vancouver  
Steph    Sa      Vancouver  
Victor   Jones   Toronto
Stacy    Lee     Markham
Stac     Lee     Markham
Stacy    Lee     Calgary
```

There are some typos, in columns in first and last name.  I tried to create an unique identifier and use a groupby statement to isolate likely typos.

Likely typos I think would fall under this category
Match

- if ID1 matches another ID1 and ID2 doesn't match
- if ID2 matches another ID2 and ID1 doesn't match

This is my desired dataset of likely typos

```
First    Last    Location     ID1              ID2
John     Smith   Toronto      JohnToronto      SmithToronto
Joh      Smith   Toronto      JohToronto       SmithToronto
Steph    Sax     Vancouver    StephVancouver   SaxVancouver  
Steph    Sa      Vancouver    StephVancouver   SaVancouver    
Stacy    Lee     Markham      StacyMarkham     LeeMarkham
Stac     Lee     Markham      StacMarkham      LeeMarkham
```

This is the code I tried so far

```
df["ID1"] = df["First"] + df["Location"]
df["ID2"] = df["Last"] + df["Location"]

m1 = df.groupby('ID1')['ID2'].transform('nunique').gt(1)
m2 = df.groupby('ID2')['ID1'].transform('nunique').gt(1)

out = df[m1|m2]
```

EDIT: full code, that isn't working.  It isn't filtering out for matching in ID2 but not matching in ID1.  Not picking up Stacy Lee from Markham...

```
   data = {'First':['John', 'John', 'Joh', 'Steph','Steph','Victor','Stacy','Stac','Stacy'],
    'Last':['Smith','Smith','Smith','Sax','Sa','Jones','Lee','Lee','Lee'],
     'Location':['Caglary','Toronto','Toronto','Vancouver','Vancouver','Toronto','Markham','Markahm','Calgary']}
```

Create DataFrame

```
df10 = pd.DataFrame(data)

df10["ID1"] = df10["First"] +df10["Location"]
df10["ID2"] = df10["Last"] + df10["Location"]

m1 = df10.groupby('ID1')['ID2'].transform('nunique').gt(1)
m2 = df10.groupby('ID2')['ID1'].transform('nunique').gt(1)

out = df10[m1|m2]
```

Comment: What's the question here? Your code works for me.

Comment: I tired the code, it isn't working....

Comment: Run this print statement to see what running your code produces for me: `print("   First   Last   Location             ID1           ID2\n1   John  Smith    Toronto     JohnToronto  SmithToronto\n2    Joh  Smith    Toronto      JohToronto  SmithToronto\n3  Steph    Sax  Vancouver  StephVancouver  SaxVancouver\n4  Steph     Sa  Vancouver  StephVancouver   SaVancouver\n6  Stacy    Lee    Markham    StacyMarkham    LeeMarkham\n7   Stac    Lee    Markham     StacMarkham    LeeMarkham")`

Comment: @richardec I dont think it is picking up the example StacyLee and StacLee

Comment: That's because in your example data after the edit the values for `ID1` for `Stacy/Stac Lee` *are* different. Look at your `Location`, for for `Stacy/Stac Lee` you have `Mar*kha*m` and `Mar*kah*m`. If you use the first dataframe on your question your code works fine.

Comment: WOW THANKS!   SUCH A SILL MISTAKE

Answer (score 0):

Code works,

I just had typos...

```
m1 = df10.groupby('ID1')['ID2'].transform('nunique').gt(1)
m2 = df10.groupby('ID2')['ID1'].transform('nunique').gt(1)

out = df10[m1|m2]
```